# Split String after comment ended or end statement

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a code :

```
String code = "class foo { // class named foo\n
                   public void fo() { // a method no parameter named fo\n
                       int[]a = {\n
                           1,2,3,4\n
                       };\n
                       for(int b : a){ // loop b as many as a\n
                           if(b%2==0){\n
                               System.out.println(b); // print out b\n
                           }\n
                       }\n
                   }\n
               }";
```

So, I want to split the code into separate strings after every end of comment  or end of a statement. Here is an example :

```
1. class foo { // class named foo
2. public void fo() { // a method no parameter named fo
3. int[]a = {
       1,2,3,4
   };
4. for(int b : a){ // loop b as many as a
5. if(b%2==0){
       System.out.println(b); // print out b
```

I was trying make code :

```
for(String get : code.split("(?<=;)|(?<=;(//.+))"))
```

But, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints out exactly what you want to achieve...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String code = "class foo { // class named foo\n" + 
                      "public void fo() { // a method no parameter named fo\n" + 
                      "int[]a = {\n" + 
                      " 1,2,3,4\n" + "};\n" + 
                      "for(int b : a){ // loop b as many as a\n" + 
                      "if(b%2==0){\n" + 
                      " System.out.println(b); // print out b\n" + 
                      "}\n" + "}\n" + "}\n" + "}";

        String requiredData = "";
        short count = 1;
        for (String data : code.split("\n")) {
            if (data.contains("//") || data.contains(";")) {
                requiredData = requiredData + data;
                System.out.println(count + ". " + requiredData);
                requiredData = "";
                count++;
            } else {
                if (requiredData.isEmpty())
                    requiredData = data + "\n";
                else
                    requiredData = requiredData + data + "\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the output of the above code...

```
1. class foo { // class named foo
2. public void fo() { // a method no parameter named fo
3. int[]a = {
    1,2,3,4
};
4. for(int b : a){ // loop b as many as a
5. if(b%2==0){
    System.out.println(b); // print out b
```

Comment: i want same like my output.

Comment: @newbie couldn't you have done that yourself? it's a pretty straight forward change. i have modified my answer to give the output you wanted. please go through it...

Answer (score 1):

Can you not split by the newline character.Like this :

```
for(String x: code.split("(\r?\n)")){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Comment: my goal is separate every ended stament